# how do i best structure an angular app centered around one big heavy non-angular library (this case: openlayers map)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers, openlayers-3

Often non-angular libraries **instantiate and bind an object to the DOM** and provide functions to work with it, in my case its the 'map' in openlayers 3.

**How do i best deal with libraries like this in angular to allow me to work with the 'object' from every part of the app?**

- A Service that holds the instance and wraps callable functions for the instance?
- A Directive that i somehow communicate with (mostly service i guess) that holds the instance?
- A global object that i directly call everything on? (sounds like a really bad way)
- Put it all in a utility object that wraps/expands the openlayers functions with my own things and access it everywhere?

For another project I wanted to reuse as much legacy code as possible and wrapped everything necessary in a service that instantiates a map object.

*For a new project i have no legacy code and can act freely.*

A openlayers directive library like azimuthjs (https://github.com/mpriour/azimuthjs) is not a real solution

Comment: The short answer is - create a wrapper directive and expose via isolate scope only the things that you are interested in and grow it as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a "main" controller, close to the DOM tree managed by Angular, and create and store the "map" object in that main controller.

Storing the map object in a controller that is "low" in the DOM managed by Angular makes it possible to share/pass the map with/to other scopes/components of the Angular app.

The JS code:

```js
function MainController() {
  this.map = new ol.Map({
    // ...
  });
}
```

The HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app='app'>
  <head>
    <title>Simple example</title>
    ...
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <div id="map" map-directive="ctrl.map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above example, a "main" controller is created on the page body. That controller creates and stores the OpenLayers map.

The map is then passed to a `map-directive`, which is responsible for inserting the map into the DOM (the directive's `link` function calls `setTarget` on the map). In the same way, the map could be passed to other directives of the application.

This approach is the one we're adopting in the [ngeo](https://github.com/camptocamp/ngeo) project, whose goal is to provide directives and services easing the development of apps based on Angular and OpenLayers 3.

For more detail on the approach, see the "simple" example ([HTML](https://github.com/camptocamp/ngeo/blob/master/examples/simple.html), [JS](https://github.com/camptocamp/ngeo/blob/master/examples/simple.js)), and the [`ngeo-map`](https://github.com/camptocamp/ngeo/blob/master/src/directives/map.js) directive in ngeo. You can also have a look at the other ngeo examples.

Answer (score 0):

The service option which wraps the instances callable functions seems your best bet. 
Angular services are intended to be used to provide "global" access to code likely to be used throughout your application and as such are Singletons.

You also get the benefits of dependency injection making it easier to swap out your underlying code library with another if needed.

You might also consider creating multiple services each exposing a particular aspect or related group of functions from your library.